# Can't get real element height in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I need to fit text in two rows. I have React component but I can't get updated height - only height after element rendered. This is my component

```
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      text: props.text
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)
    let parent = element.parentNode
    let originalText = element.innerText
    let containerHeight = parent.offsetHeight
    let temp = originalText
    if (containerHeight < element.offsetHeight) {
       while(containerHeight < ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).offsetHeight) {
           temp = temp.substr(0, temp.length-1)
           this.setState({
             text: temp
           })
           i++
           console.log(temp,containerHeight,ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).offsetHeight);
       }

       temp = temp.substr(0, temp.length-4) + '...'

       this.setState({
         text: temp
       })
     }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        {this.state.text}
      </span>
    )
  }
```

How I can get element height after each re-render?

**PS I found problem:**

I should use componentDidUpdate() here and I don't need to use `while` in componentDidUpdate() method, because it's triggered each time when I updated state.

Comment: Do you really need the inner text of the parent? ```let element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)
    let parent = element.parentNode
    let originalText = element.innerText```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You registered the trigger `componentDidMount`. You should register also `componentDidUpdate`.

Check this document to understand the lifecycle in react:

https://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/

Comment: I also tried to add it to componentDidUpdate . But element.offsetHeight returned not correct values

Comment: Then put your example into a minimal reproducible code. Btw I think that you shouldn't be getting the innerText of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount` is being called only once, after the component has been mounted. Check react lifecycle [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) for more information.

The methods that are being called again when your component state has been updated and is being re-rendered are(in that order):

```
componentWillReceiveProps()
shouldComponentUpdate()
componentWillUpdate()
render()
componentDidUpdate()
```

Since you need to re-calculate the height after your component has been re-rendered put your logic inside `componentDidUpdate` and you should be set.